# Is there a way to initialize fields in two structs with a circular reference?

Tags: rust

I have two structs that refer to each other. Once initialized, they are never mutated for the rest of the application's lifetime.

It's possible to wrap them in a `Mutex` or `RwLock` or something, but it'd be nice not to deal with those throughout the codebase, just to get things initialized.

Here's the example code (does not compile):

```
use std::sync::Arc;
struct First {
    second: Option<Second>,
}

struct Second {
    first: Option<Arc<First>>,
}

fn main() {
    let first = Arc::new(First { second: None });
    let mut second = Second { first: None };
    second.first = Some(first.clone());
    first.second = Some(second);
}
```

The problem:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to data in an `Arc`
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 |     first.second = Some(second);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign
   |
   = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `Arc<First>`
```

It's clear what's happening here; it's not possible to assign to `first`, because it's inside an `Arc`, which does not allow interior mutability.

Changing the order of operations doesn't get around the problem.

Using `Arc::get_mut()` won't work, because the `Arc` is cloned for storage in `second.first`.

So, is it possible to create objects with this pattern without needing runtime locking?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, depending on if you need `Sync` or not.

With `Sync` you need some synchronization structure, a `RwLock` should do:

```rust
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use std::sync::RwLock;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct First {
    second: Option<Second>,
}

struct Second {
    first: Option<Arc<RwLock<First>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let first = Arc::new(RwLock::new(First { second: None }));
    let mut second = Second { first: None };
    second.first = Some(first.clone());
    let mut inner = first.write().unwrap();
    inner.second = Some(second);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=369d53c1cd5704eaac7a704f401ffa8b)

If you do not need `Sync`, use `Rc` instead of `Arc` and [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct First {
    second: Option<Second>,
}

struct Second {
    first: Option<Rc<RefCell<First>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let first = Rc::new(RefCell::new(First { second: None }));
    let mut second = Second { first: None };
    second.first = Some(first.clone());
    first.borrow_mut().second = Some(second);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6df251b391d5331ce9737045bba2297c)

Comment: @SvenMarnach, actually, you are right. It should be either `Arc<RwLock>` or `Rc<RefCell>`.